# CSS applying in Internet explorer 7 but not in firefox 3.5?

Tags: css, firefox, xhtml, cross-browser

[See Year's TAB 2009/2010 of this page in IE7 than firefox](http://www.bookergroup.com/media-centre/press%20-releases/2009.aspx)

Tab's styling not applying in Firefox but applying in IE.

I want to apply same style (Which is showing in IE7) in FF too.

**Update:**

problem fixed now but through !important

Comment: Could you be more specific about what your problem actually is?

Comment: In firefox tabs are displayed as a text in a column. 2009 then below 2010. In IE they are tabs.

@Jitendra: You must provide code segment for tab creation.

Comment: but i though live example would be better option and i assume everyone has Firefox with firebug. and which code u r suggesting of Tab XHTML or CSS or both.

Comment: Firebug is very helpful when you have styling, not when it's missing... The Chrome DOM inspector was helpful though, it works there too.

Comment: It's strange, Why downvoting? What is not clear in question and is it not related to SO?

Comment: A live example is fine, but it also means that you have to dig through a lot of code, styles and markup to actually find the issue. Providing the CSS styles that are actually used and therefore likely to be causing the problem helps finding the answer quicker.

Comment: @Anne Schuessler - u r righ but this case is different. prblem is css not applying to firefox so i didn't pasted code. because css only applying in IE 7.First time i'm facing this problem

Comment: @Jitendra It is generally best to try to isolate your problem down to a small example that demonstrates the issue. Try to keep removing more and more stuff from the HTML, and from the CSS, until you get something that has only what is absolutely necessary to demonstrate the problem. During this process, you may discover the problem yourself; but if you do not, you will have a much shorter piece of code for other people to look at, so they can more easily isolate the problem instead of having to dig through your whole page in several browsers to figure out what you're even asking about.

Comment: I don't see anything different between IE8 and Firefox (all text, no tabs; it really took me sometime to figure out what you are asking). Since IE8 is newer than IE7, I think what you need to do is to make it compliant to IE8/Fx. And if you really want an answer, you should post the core css/js which created the tab.

Comment: @Jitendra I'd say that the CSS in general *is* applying to firefox, ie and whatnot. The funny thing is that when I open the page, it looks fine in Chrome 4, but is displayed as simple text in IE 8. Things like that can usually be traced back to a limited selection of CSS styles that aren't properly supported by certain browsers.

Comment: yes it's fixed now but through !important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The styling works in IE 7 but not in IE 8 or Firefox.

In the file inner-pages.css the style #RNSViewIssue is missing the closing bracket, which causes the rest of the file to be ignored.

In the file main.css the style #share-price-calculatorSharePriceComparatorSectionContainer (and co.) has a starting parenthesis instead of a starting bracket, causing the rest of the file to be ignored.

There are plenty of other errors in the css files, but those are the ones that are directly responsible for your problems.

In Firefox open the error console and then browse to the page, and it will give you a list of all errors in the css files.

Comment: @Guffa - ok checking thanks. but it's strange why it's showing fine in IE7. although I've solved problem with !important.

Comment: Obviously IE 7 has some other way of handling syntax errors in CSS, so that the result differs. That is probably because IE 8 (and Firefox) supports some new CSS standards that IE 7 doesn't.